# Groovy Mocked methods return null when called inside code from a Library

Tags: java, maven, unit-testing, groovy, spock

I'm developing a Java project that has several modules. I decided to create a Module just for testing, where the "java" folder is empty and the "test" folder has all the project's unit and integration tests.

I'm having trouble with a test where I mock MyClass1's getText() method. It works fine if I call getText() somewhere within the Groovy test files, but it's returning null when it gets called from within MyClass2's methods. I suspect it has to do with how the Groovy files get compiled to allow method mocking, whereas MyClass1 and MyClass2 are already compiled since they're from a library. Here's somewhat what my code looks like:

Classes from Module1

```
public final class MyClass1 {
  private String text;

  public MyClass1() {
    text = "Hello there!";
  }

  public String getText() {
    return text;
  }
}

public class MyClass2 {
  private MyClass1 myObject1;

  public MyClass2(MyClass1 myObject1) {
    this.myObject1 = myObject1;
  }

  public String toLowerCase() {
    return myObject1.getText().toLowerCase();
  }
}
```

Tests:

```
def assertTextNotNull(MyClass1 myObject1) {
  assert myObject1.getText() != null;
}

def "successful test"() {
  given:
  MyClass1 myMock1 = GroovyMock(MyClass1);

  myMock1.getText() >> "ABC";

  assertTextNotNull(myMock1);
}

def "unsuccessful test"() {
  given:
  MyClass1 myMock1 = GroovyMock(MyClass1); // I need to use GroovyMock here because the actual class I'm mocking is final
  MyClass2 myObject2 = new MyClass2(myMock1);

  myMock1.getText() >> "ABC";

  when:
  assertTextNotNull(myMock1);

  then:
  myObject2.toLowerCase() == "abc"; // Fails here because myObject1.getText() returns an empty String ""
}
```

My test module's pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
        <artifactId>myParentArtifactId</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>myArtifactId-tests</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>17</release>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>

                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/*IT.*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*UT.*</include>
                        <include>**/*UnitTest.*</include>
                        <include>**/*UT.groovy</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M7</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*UT.*</exclude>
                                <exclude>**/*UnitTest.*</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                                <include>**/*IntegrationTest.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <!-- The gmavenplus plugin is used to compile Groovy code. To learn
                    more about this plugin, visit https://github.com/groovy/GMavenPlus/wiki -->
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.13.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>addSources</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>papermc</id>
            <url>https://repo.papermc.io/repository/maven-public/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Paper/Waterfall -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.papermc.paper</groupId>
            <artifactId>paper-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.2-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.waterfallmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>waterfall-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.18-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- All other modules -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>myGroupId</groupId>
            <artifactId>myArtifactId-module1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Testing related -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>5.8.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
            <!-- Enables mocking of classes without default constructor (together with CGLIB) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.objenesis</groupId>
            <artifactId>objenesis</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2-M1-groovy-4.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I've searched far and wide on StackOverflow. It seems like people only have issues with mocked methods returning null when they're using their own code, and not library code. Hence, I found no solution.

What can I do to make sure getText() returns the mocked reply independently from where it's called?

EDIT:

There has been a development. I basically copy-pasted the code I pasted here into a new module and made MyClass1 final just like it is in the library. It didn't work, as expected. By removing the final on the class declaration, the tests suddenly worked. So, the conclusion I can take from this is that Mocking final class's methods only works inside groovy code. Those methods can be called from within library/other module's code but will return a default value (in my case, null. In the posted code's case, an empty String).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mock final classes for Java with Spock. And `GroovyMock` only works for code written in (dynamic) Groovy as you suspected.

However, there is [spock-mockable](https://github.com/joke/spock-mockable/), it is an extension, that will use a java agent to transparently remove the `final` modifier from the configured classes, methods, and fields. Using this extension, you can use the standard `Mock` method from Spock to mock the now non-final class.

```
@Mockable(MyClass1)
class ASpec extends Specification {

def "unsuccessful test"() {
  given:
  MyClass1 myMock1 = Mock() // I need to use GroovyMock here because the actual class I'm mocking is final
  MyClass2 myObject2 = new MyClass2(myMock1)

  myMock1.getText() >> "ABC"

  when:
  assertTextNotNull(myMock1)

  then:
  myObject2.toLowerCase() == "abc" // Fails here because myObject1.getText() returns an empty String ""
}
}
```